# How to Sum Each Enum Value in a Different Column and Don't Repeat Person's Name?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, enums

Let's say I have a table with `SellerId`, `DateTime`, `ProductType` to register each time a a Seller sells a product. The ProductType is from `ENUM` type with {0=Phone, 1=Recharge, 2=SimCard}. Then I have a table with `SellerId` and `SellerName`.

I want to make a Stored Procedure that shows this view:

```
  ID | NAME | Phones | Recharges | SimCards | Total
 ----|------|--------|-----------|----------|-------
  05 | Eddy |      6 |         7 |        0 |    13
```

I know how to `join` the two tables to get the ID and NAME in this view, but I do not know how to `SUM` each `ProductType` into a different column. And I also wanted only one row for each ID/NAME.

Can anyone show me how to achieve this in this simple example?

Comment: Please look into the PIVOT function.

Comment: I tried to adapt with examples from http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query but I could not understand because I did not found examples specific for use with ENUM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer using a dynamic `PIVOT`.  I've created a 3rd table on the fly called #ProdType which contains your enum values... this is entirely optional, but makes it easier to maintain, as you just add to the table to add a column... you can see I added "Cases" and "Screens" as Product 3/4 respectively.

```
/* IF TEMP TABLES EXIST, DROP THEM */
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SELLER') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #SELLER
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PRODTYPE') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #PRODTYPE
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DATA') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DATA

/* SETUP TEST TABLES */
CREATE TABLE #SELLER (SELLERID INT, NAME NVARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE #DATA (SELLERID INT, SALEDATE DATETIME, PRODUCTTYPE INT)

INSERT INTO #SELLER (SELLERID, NAME) 
VALUES (5, 'Eddy'), (6,'Dave')

INSERT INTO #DATA (SELLERID, SALEDATE, PRODUCTTYPE)
VALUES (5, GETDATE(), 0),(5, GETDATE(), 0),(5, GETDATE(), 0),(5, GETDATE(), 0),(5, GETDATE(), 0),(5, GETDATE(), 0),
       (5, GETDATE(), 1),(5, GETDATE(), 1),(5, GETDATE(), 1),(5, GETDATE(), 1),(5, GETDATE(), 1),(5, GETDATE(), 1),(5, GETDATE(), 1),
       (6, GETDATE(), 0)

/* MAINTAIN THIS TABLE WITH YOUR ENUM VALUES*/
CREATE TABLE #PRODTYPE (PRODUCTTYPE INT, NAME NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO #PRODTYPE (PRODUCTTYPE, NAME)
VALUES (0, 'Phone'), 
       (1, 'Recharge'), 
       (2, 'SimCard'), 
       (3, 'Case'), 
       (4, 'Screen')

/* MAIN QUERY */          
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @sql  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF(
(SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(y) AS [text()]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT NAME AS y FROM #PRODTYPE) AS Y
ORDER BY y
FOR XML PATH('')),
1, 1, N'');        

SET @sql = 'SELECT SellerID, Name, '+@cols+', '+REPLACE(@cols,',','+')+' AS Total
            FROM (SELECT S.SELLERID, S.NAME, P.NAME AS PTYPE
                  FROM #DATA D 
                  JOIN #SELLER S ON D.SELLERID=S.SELLERID
                  JOIN #PRODTYPE P ON D.PRODUCTTYPE = P.PRODUCTTYPE) SUB
            PIVOT (COUNT([PTYPE]) FOR PTYPE IN ('+@cols+')) AS P'
PRINT @SQL
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select t1.sellerid, t1.sellername,
       sum(case when ProductType = 0 then 1 end) as Phones,
       sum(case when ProductType = 1 then 1 end) as Recharges,
       sum(case when ProductType = 2 then 1 end) as SimCards,
       count(t2.ProductType) as Total,
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.sellerid = t2.sellerid
group by t1.sellerid, t1.sellername
```